# "Place block" ajax error when using nginx

Tags: ajax, 8

I'm having a lot of trouble configuring nginx properly for Drupal 8. Using the [Drupal nginx recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/) on the official site works well except for opening modal dialogs like the "Place block" dialog. This results in a 200OK response but an ajax error.

Here is a [gist with the error](https://gist.github.com/tanc/5a34d658f44a47c3c28b5ce98f234244).

I know this is an nginx configuration issue as I have a [different conf](https://github.com/Wodby/drupal-nginx/blob/master/drupal8.conf) file that doesn't cause this issue. This other configuration doesn't work with Drupal 8's active link javascript due to the way it adds the query parameters. Frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes writing it down helps to figure things out! The missing bit of configuration needed is `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;`

With the Drupal nginx recipe but with that line added in the `location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {` block its now working as expected, both the `is-active` class is added to the active menu link and the "Place block" ajax works properly.

Comment: Have issued a [pull request](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-wiki/pull/315) with the change for the nginx recipe.